# How to correctly import method from another package

Tags: go, methods, import, package

I have the following simple project:

```
myapp/
    |- mainlib/main.go
    |- tables/sometable.go
```

In sometable.go I have:

```
package tables

import (
    "fmt"
)

type TableName string

func (table TableName) GetDataFromDataSource() string {
    return "getdatafromdatasource"
}
```

Those are methods, and now I want to use them in main.go:

```
package main

import t myapp/tables

type tableName t.TableName // and such "attempts"
```

I've tried:

```
t.GetDataFromDataSource()
t.tableName("string").GetDataFromDataSource()
tableName("string").GetDataFromDataSource()
```

and similar combinations and compiler says "undefined reference" still...

So, my question is: how to correctly use method from another package in such context? Of course my methods starts with captial letters and are exported. If I try to use simple function with same name (not method), then it works correctly...

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with packages, but with alias declaration vs type definition.

Let's take a simple example:

```
type A string

func (a A) Print() {
    fmt.Println(a)
}

type B A
type C = A

func main() {
    A("A").Print()
    B("B").Print()
    C("C").Print()
}
```

This fails to compile on line `B("B").Print()` with:

> B("B").Print undefined (type B has no field or method Print)

The spec clearly spells out the difference in the [type declarations section](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations)

The line `type B A` is a type definition:

> A type definition creates a new, distinct type with the same
>   underlying type and operations as the given type, and binds an
>   identifier to it.

While the line `type C = A` is an alias declaration:

> An alias declaration binds an identifier to the given type.

The former is a new type, so the receiver type `A` for method `Print()` will not match the type `B`.
The latter is just a name pointing to type `A`.

You'll want to change your code to the following, using type aliases:

```
import t myapp/tables

type tableName = t.TableName

tableName("string").GetDataFromDataSource()
```

And a few notes:

- `t.GetDataFromDataSource()` can't work, it's a method and needs a receiver
- `t.tableName("string").GetDataFromDataSource()` won't work, `t.tableName` is not a thing, or if it is, it's not exported
- you can't talk about importing methods, only packages are imported. A method is either exported or not, but it's the package you import